# Error with npm start in terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal

I'm trying to run 'npm start' and terminal is giving me the following error:

```
> payments@1.0.0 start /Users/shawnmurray
> node app.js

module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/shawnmurray/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! payments@1.0.0 start: `node app.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the payments@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /Users/shawnmurray/.npm/_logs/2017-11-26T01_03_27_930Z-debug.log 

shawns-iMac:~ shawnmurray$ node -version node: bad option: -version 
shawns-iMac:~ shawnmurray$ node --version 
v8.9.1
```

I've attempted several other solutions such as uninstalling the node_modules folder but that didn't help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a file at `/Users/shawnmurray/app.js` ?

Comment: When I saved the file app.js, I placed it on the desktop.

Comment: @AlexMcMillon So you're thinking I should place app.js on /Users/shawnmurray/app.js?

Comment: Well, considering you are asking `node` to run the file `/Users/shawnmurray/app.js`, that could be a start.. yea.

Comment: @mur7ay Why would you place it on the desktop when you are in `/Users/shawnmurray`?

Comment: @mur7ay How in the world would the computer know to go to your desktop to find that file??

Comment: Thats true! I thought I placed the other file on there as well. Trying your solution now.

Comment: Stupid mistake. It worked! Thanks fellas.